# Quadrant problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

$(-1+i)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

here, $\tan\theta=-1$

so,

$\theta=\tan^{-1}(-1)=\tan^{-1}(\tan(-\frac{\pi}{4}))=\tan^{-1}(\tan(\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}))=\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}$

#### My question is why can't i write $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw a quick picture. The complex number $-1+i$ is in the second quadrant. (Note that the equation $\tan \theta = a$ has two solutions in $(-\pi, \pi]$ and the numbers $-1+i$ and $1-i$ do not have the same argument.)

Comment: Is that a complex number always in first and second quadrant?   Could you please explain the $\tan \theta=\alpha$?

Comment: The number $1-i$ is in the fourth quadrant, and this one also has $\tan \theta = -1$. Until you feel comfortable with arguments of complex numbers, always draw quick pictures: place the number in a coordinate system.

Comment: One more question. How $\tan(-\frac{\pi}{4})=\tan(\pi-\frac{\pi}{4})$?

Comment: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28-pi%2F4%29%3Dtan%28pi-pi%2F4%29)i got the solution of how $\tan(\frac{-\pi}{4})=\tan(\pi-\frac{-\pi}{4})$. But is there any shortcut way to verify the identity $\tan(\frac{-\pi}{4})=\tan(\pi-\frac{-\pi}{4})$ immediately ?

Comment: $\tan$ is periodic with period $\pi$, i.e. $\tan(x+\pi) = \tan x$ for all $x$.